# Выделение элемента синим цветом при нажатии на телефоне

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я нажимаю на элемент `li` для выбора ответа на вопрос, весь элемент выделяется синим цветом. Как можно это исправить? Такое поведение происходит на телефоне

```css
.radio {
  display: none;
}

.radio-custom {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border: solid 2px #cbcbcb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
}

.radio-custom,
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.label {
  padding-left: 23px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
  @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

.radio:checked+.radio-custom {
  border: none;
}

.radio:checked+.radio-custom::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  background: url(../../../../../images/checked-mark.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
}

.answer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1031px;
  @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    width: calc(100% - 51.5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
           <input class="radio" type="radio" name="radio-test">
           <span class="radio-custom"></span>
           <div class="answer"><span class="label">Никто не знает</span></div>
         </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
           <input class="radio" type="radio" name="radio-test">
           <span class="radio-custom"></span>
           <div class="answer">
             <span class="label">Никто не знает</span>
           </div>
         </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label> 
          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="radio-test">
          <span class="radio-custom"></span>
          <div class="answer">
            <span class="label">Никто не знает</span>
          </div>
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
          <input class="radio" type="radio" name="radio-test">
          <span class="radio-custom"></span>
          <div class="answer">
            <span class="label">Никто не знает</span>
          </div>
        </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При `:focus` задать, а вернее отключить стили `outline`
https://webref.ru/css/outline